# Google Calendar API with domain wide delegation: events.watch method fails with "The request is missing a valid API key"

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

## Background

I have followed all of the steps for domain wide delegation. An example of this is the ability to sign in with the service account json, impersonate users in my Google Workspace account and list their events (see example below).

```
# list-events.py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from pprint import pprint

def create_calendar_api_service(service_acc_filepath):
    """Build and return a Google Calendar service object authorized with the service
    account that acts on behalf of a given user.

    Args:
        service_acc_filepath: path to service account json with domain wide delegation enabled.
    """
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        service_acc_filepath, scopes=str(SCOPES)
    )
    # impersonate user with emailaddress=calendarId
    delegate = credentials.create_delegated(USER_EMAIL)
    return build("calendar", "v3", credentials=delegate)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    UUID = get_uuid()
    SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE_PATH = "./workspace-sa/my-project-d2355248f03f.json"
    USER_EMAIL = "workspace-user-1@company.com"
    BASE_URL = "https://acf1-92-233-162-75.eu.ngrok.io"

    
    # get authenticated object to interact with Google API.
    my_service = create_query_api_service(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE_PATH)

    req = my_service.events().list(calendarId=f"{USER_EMAIL}").execute()
```

The problem I am having is that the **same** setup doesn't let me receive notifications from the watch() method...

```
# watch-for-events.py
...
body = {
        "id": f"{UUID}",
        "type": "webhook",
        "address": f"{BASE_URL}/calendar-push",  # The URL to which notifications are delivered for this channel.
    }

my_service = create_calendar_api_service(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE_PATH)

req = my_service.events().watch(calendarId=f"{USER_EMAIL}", body=body).execute()
```

Running the watch() method returns the following to the terminal.

```
{'expiration': '1669901130000',
 'id': '0184a9d0-8b55-c62d-ee15-84891fcf1014',
 'kind': 'api#channel',
 'resourceId': '7kxHSfF9AbNVLSXk5cxPcmgfhAg',
 'resourceUri': 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/workspace-user-1%40company.com/events?alt=json'}
```

Upon following the resourceUri I see the aforementioned error message.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

## The Main Problem

very single change in the target calendar hits my https webhook/endpoint with a `400 BAD REQUEST`.

I cannot even read the request in my Flask backend.

## Question

Can someone please help me understand why I am not able to receive push notifications (why they all return 400 BAD REQUEST)?

PS: I have read that I can provide some further access credentials via a bearer token in the header. But there is no header attribute in these methods.

Here are the images below for the workspace admin settings in question:
[image: The scopes permitted to the service account whose json we're using in the ServiceAccountCredentials() method]

## Endpoint code

```
@app.route("/calendar-push", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def add_message():
    app.logger.info("HIT THE /calendar_push ROUTE")
    content = request.json
    app.logger.info(content)
    return request.json
```

### Output from flask endpoint after moving calendar events

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Nov/2022 17:39:50] "POST /calendar-push HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

Comment: am i to understanding you are trying to visit resourceUri with out authorization?

Comment: Hi @DaImTo. Good question!

To clarify. I just clicked on the resourceUri to get more information while debugging the main issue and I noticed this error `"The request is missing a valid API key."` 

The main error is that every single change in the target calendar that hits my https webhook/endpoint fails with a 400 BAD REQUEST. 

My ability to access `resourceUri` on my browser is just additional information that I thought could help - but may well be not causing the main error.

*Added formatting to the question to make this more clear*

Comment: you need to be authorized to see that link.  As in authorization header, im just wondering why you are trying to click that link

Comment: I was trying to click that link because someone else on Stack overflow mentioned it in a similar question. Sorry for any confusion. I only want to know how to receive push notifications using the watch () method. (I.e. How to debug the BAD REQUEST 400).

Comment: then should come in on the endpoint you submited BASE_URL = "https://acf1-92-233-162-75.eu.ngrok.io"

Comment: That's correct. The problem is that the endpoint only shows a very basic error message. It does not show the why the request is "BAD".

* Edited question to show Endpoint code and lack of error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249867/discussion-between-hkh-and-daimto).

Comment: if you check this i should be in chat most of the day

Comment: If your  issue is resolved , can you please provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Comment: Hi @HemanthKumar. Unfortunately I was not able to resolve this. I switched from trying to implement it myself to using hosted services that deal with these issues for you.

Answer (score 0):

> 'resourceUri': 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/workspace-user-1%40company.com/events?alt=json'

All that is is telling you what notification endpoint the message response is for.

In which case you will need to do a

```
events = service.events().list(calendarId='workspace-user-1%40company.com').execute()
```

Your getting missing api key because your calling the endpoint without first being authorized.

Authorize the call then check it and you will get a response.